# questions about implementation of drawing triangle in java

Tags: java, swing

I am learning myself about drawing in java , I found this code , I have some questions about the implementation of the code , Please see the code below :

```
package shapes;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.sun.glass.events.WindowEvent;

public class drawTriangle extends Frame {

    public Polygon mypolygon = new Polygon();

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D ga = (Graphics2D) g;
        ga.setPaint(Color.red);
        ga.drawPolygon(mypolygon);

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(200);
        list.add(100);
        list.add(950);
        list.add(950);
        list.add(100);
        list.add(200);
        list.add(list.get(0));
        list.add(list.get(1));

        drawTriangle frame = new drawTriangle();
        for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++ ) {
            int x= list.get(i++);
            int y= list.get(i);

            frame.mypolygon.addPoint(x,y);

        }

        frame.addWindowStateListener(new WindowAdapter()

            { public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }

            });
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

First question ) When I run the code I get a window with a drawn triangle ... 
When I press to remove the window it does not work..
I tried to put `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` or `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(drawTriangle.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` but does not work.
I changed `System.exit(0);` to `System.exit(1);` but does not remove the window . How to remove the window after I run the code ?

Second question ) what is the difference between `public Polygon mypolygon = new Polygon();` and `drawTriangle frame = new drawTriangle();` ?

Third question )  what is the meaning of the code below !!!

```
int x= list.get(i++);
int y= list.get(i);
```

Forth question ) what does this do `Graphics2D ga = (Graphics2D) g;` ?

Thanks

Comment: use `addWindowListener` instead of `addWindowStateListener` .to close the frame .you are using awt frame not swing jframe so `setDefaultCloseOperation` doesn't work

Comment: I did that but I still can not close it .. thanks

Comment: remove `import com.sun.glass.events.WindowEvent;` and add `import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;`  you are not using correct `WindowEvent` class

Comment: *"Forth question.."*  Each thread should be about one specific question  SO is not a help desk, or a place to find a tutor.

Comment: brother Fast Snail , you are best .. you are so cleaver , thank you dude

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You should never overwrite pant method, you should use `paintComponent` in this case. If you do, you should call `super.paint(g)` at the beginning of your `paint` (this is why your window doesn't close with `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)`).
2. `Polygon` is graphics primitive, `Graphics` is graphics context of drawing component, but swing always allocates `Graphics2D` which more featured.
3. If you want to use more featured class you need to cast.
4. `new Polygon` creates new primitive for drawing, `new drawTringle` creates new `JFrame`.
5. In `main` x and y coordinates are collected on linear list. Then they unrolled to get x,y pair again.

Comment: thank you ,, I did not understand "In main x and y coordinates are collected on linear list. Then they unrolled to get x,y pair again." ... what is Then they unrolled to get x,y pair again.?

Comment: @krzydyn but awt frame doesn't have a `setDefaultCloseOperation` method

Comment: @Fast Snail, right. If he inherits from awt Frame, then need add listener, and overwrite paint not paintComponent.

Comment: @ Fast Snail what does it have ?

Comment: @code for awt frame use  `System.exit(0);` as you did .how ever awt is very old framework so use swing .you have already imported swing frame